# How to calculate Earned Premium between two dates till @AsOfDate and break it down by each month in DAX

Tags: powerbi, dax, powerbi-embedded

I have Premium for a policy with `TransactionEffectiveDate` and `TransactionExpirationDate`.

Is any way to write  query in DAX that would take each premium amount and break it down by the month between those two dates.

The @AsOfDate parameter will be the date the policy stops Earning.

For Example:

`PolicyNumber WIC1000158-00` 
has Premium of $82,913 
and  `TransactionEffectiveDate 1/5/2018`

and `TransactionExpirationDate 1/5/2019.`

which gives us total of 365 days of Policy life.

Let see how much we Earned till '06/29/2018'

So Premium of 82,913 should be broken down by 12 month:

So for the first Policy month we have only 27 days

So 82,913/365 * 27 = 6,133.29  -thats how much its been earned in the first month.

And so on until the `@AsOfDate`.

The result should be like that with @AsOfDate = `'6/29/2018'`:

[image]

Although I only need columns 
`YearNum`,
 `MonthNum`,
 `Qtr`,`EarnedPremium`

I was able to write it in SQL but 
Is any way to  achieve that in DAX?

.pbix file is availabel here: 
https://www.dropbox.com/s/pbj61vsb20qbhzm/LossTriangleTest.pbix?dl=0

---

**UPDATE**!

Alexis, thank you very much. Its amazing what DAX can do with the numbers.

For some reason its always gives me a Earned Premium total slightly more than original Premium.

For example PolicyNumber 'PACA1000101-00' has total premium $10,568 but calculates Earned as $10,596.  **April 2013** gives slightly more.

I think some additional logic need to be implemented towards the last breakdown (EndRiskMonth).

(Result from Power BI. Sorry, its not sorted yet)

[image]

Result from SQL:

[image]

As you can see April 2013 has 26 days.

This is how I do it in SQL, if it help. (can be run in SSMS)

```
DECLARE @PlazaInsuranceWPDataSet TABLE (
                                        PolicyNumber varchar(50), 
                                        TransactionEffectiveDate datetime, 
                                        TransactionExpirationDate datetime, 
                                        WrittenPremium money
                                        )
INSERT INTO @PlazaInsuranceWPDataSet values ('PACA1000101-00', '2012-04-27','2013-04-27',6630.00 ),
                                            ('PACA1000101-00', '2012-04-27','2013-04-27',1600.00 ),
                                            ('PACA1000101-00', '2012-04-27','2013-04-27',490.00 ),
                                            ('PACA1000101-00', '2012-04-27','2013-04-27',-77.00 ),
                                            ('PACA1000101-00', '2012-04-27','2013-04-27',1925.00 )

; WITH Earned_to_date AS (
   SELECT Cast('2019-06-30' AS DATE) AS Earned_to_date
), policy_data AS (
    SELECT
            PolicyNumber
,           Cast(TransactionEffectiveDate AS DATE) AS TransactionEffectiveDate
,           Cast(TransactionExpirationDate AS DATE) AS TransactionExpirationDate
,           WrittenPremium
    FROM    @PlazaInsuranceWPDataSet        
)
, digits AS (
SELECT digit
   FROM (VALUES (0), (1), (2), (3), (4)
,      (5), (6), (7), (8), (9)) AS z2 (digit)
), numbers AS (
SELECT 1000 * d4.digit + 100 * d3.digit + 10 * d2.digit + d1.digit AS number
    FROM digits AS d1
    CROSS JOIN digits AS d2
    CROSS JOIN digits AS d3
    CROSS JOIN digits AS d4
), calendar AS (
SELECT
    DateAdd(month, number, '1753-01-01') AS month_of
,   DateAdd(month, number, '1753-02-01') AS month_after
    FROM numbers
), policy_dates AS (
SELECT
    PolicyNumber
,   CASE
        WHEN month_of < TransactionEffectiveDate THEN TransactionEffectiveDate
        ELSE month_of
    END AS StartRiskMonth
,   CASE
       WHEN TransactionExpirationDate < month_after THEN TransactionExpirationDate
       WHEN Earned_to_date.Earned_to_date < month_after THEN Earned_to_date
       ELSE month_after
    END AS EndRiskMonth
,   DateDiff(day, TransactionEffectiveDate, TransactionExpirationDate) AS policy_days
,   WrittenPremium
    FROM policy_data
    JOIN calendar
        ON (policy_data.TransactionEffectiveDate < calendar.month_after
        AND calendar.month_of < policy_data.TransactionExpirationDate)
    CROSS JOIN Earned_to_date
    WHERE  month_of < Earned_to_date
)
SELECT  PolicyNumber, 
        StartRiskMonth, 
        EndRiskMonth,
        YEAR(StartRiskMonth) as YearNum,
        MONTH(StartRiskMonth) as MonthNum,
        DATEPART(qq, StartRiskMonth) AS Qtr,
        policy_days,
        sum(WrittenPremium) as WrittenPremium,
        DateDiff(day, StartRiskMonth, EndRiskMonth) AS DaysInMonth,
        sum(WrittenPremium * DateDiff(day, StartRiskMonth, EndRiskMonth) / NULLIF(policy_days,0)) as EarnedPremium
FROM    policy_dates 
GROUP BY PolicyNumber, StartRiskMonth, EndRiskMonth
,       DateDiff(day, StartRiskMonth, EndRiskMonth),policy_days
 ORDER BY PolicyNumber, StartRiskMonth
```

---

**UPDATE!**

Alexis,

I have modified "EoMonth" in Calendar table `EOMONTH([Month], 0)+1` --added + 1

In a CrossTabel `"DaysInMonth", [EndRiskMonth] - [StartRiskMonth],`  --took off 1

And for Earned Premium

```
"EarnedPremium", [Premium] *
                    DIVIDE([EndRiskMonth] - [StartRiskMonth] , [End] - [Start])) --took off 1.
```

Result now looks like this:

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should be able to do this with some `SUMMARIZE`, `ADDCOLUMNS`, and `SELECTCOLUMNS` functions.

First, create a `'Calendar'` table along these lines:

```
Calendar = SUMMARIZE(
               ADDCOLUMNS(CALENDARAUTO(),
                   "Month", EOMONTH([Date], - 1) + 1),
               [Month],
               "EoMonth", EOMONTH([Month], 0))
```

Then you can cross-join this table with your `fact_Losses` table like this:

```
CrossTable = 
    VAR CrossTables =
        CROSSJOIN(
            SUMMARIZE(fact_Losses, 
                fact_Losses[PolicyNumber],
                "Start", MIN(fact_Losses[PolicyEffectiveDate]),
                "End", MAX(fact_Losses[PolicyExpirationDate]),
                "Premium", SUM(fact_Losses[WrittenPremium])),
            'Calendar')
    VAR RiskPeriods =
        ADDCOLUMNS(
            FILTER(CrossTables,
                'Calendar'[EoMonth] >= [Start] && 'Calendar'[Month] <= [End]),
            "StartRiskMonth", IF([Start] > 'Calendar'[Month], [Start], 'Calendar'[Month]),
            "EndRiskMonth", IF([End] < 'Calendar'[EoMonth], [End], 'Calendar'[EoMonth]))
    RETURN SELECTCOLUMNS(RiskPeriods,
                "PolicyNumber", fact_Losses[PolicyNumber],
                "StartRiskMonth", [StartRiskMonth],
                "EndRiskMonth", [EndRiskMonth],
                "YearNum", YEAR('Calendar'[Month]),
                "Qtr", ROUNDUP(MONTH('Calendar'[Month])/3, 0),
                "MonthNum", MONTH('Calendar'[Month]),
                "WrittenPremium", [Premium],
                "DaysInMonth", [EndRiskMonth] - [StartRiskMonth] + 1,
                "EarnedPremium", [Premium] *
                    DIVIDE([EndRiskMonth] - [StartRiskMonth] + 1, [End] - [Start]))
```

Comment: Thanks for your help. I am trying to use `@AsOfDate` parameter that would cut off earnings if` @AsOfDate` before the expiration date. I am stuck here.