# How to break down date range by each month in DAX Power BI?

Tags: powerbi, dax, powerbi-embedded

I have two dates:

'2018-01-05'  and  '2019-01-05'

How to create calculated table to break down those dates by month.
Should look simething like that:

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are probably many ways to do this, but here's one way that combines a few different concepts:

```
Table = 
    VAR Starting = DATE(2018, 1, 5)
    VAR Ending = DATE(2019, 1, 5)
    VAR MonthTable =
        SUMMARIZE(
            ADDCOLUMNS(
                CALENDAR(Starting, Ending),
                "StartDate", EOMONTH([Date], 0) + 1),
            [StartDate],
            "EndDate", EOMONTH([StartDate], 0) + 1)
    RETURN UNION(
               ROW("StartDate", Starting, "EndDate", EOMONTH(Starting, 0) + 1),
               FILTER(MonthTable, [EndDate] < Ending && [StartDate] > Starting),
               ROW("StartDate", EOMONTH(Ending, -1) + 1, "EndDate", Ending)
                )
```

Basically, you start with the `CALENDAR` function to get all the days, tag each date with its corresponding month, and then summarize that table to just return one row for each month.

Since the first and last rows are a bit irregular, I prepended and appending those to a filtered version of the summarized month table to get your desired table.

Comment: Thank you Alexis. 
This is basically the first part of the calculation I need.
Now I need to use those dates  to break down and Calculate SUM(Earned Premium) for each month and year.. 

https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51107630/how-to-calculate-earned-premium-between-two-dates-till-asofdate-and-break-it-do

Answer (score 1):

Create new table as

```
Table = CALENDAR( DATE(2018, 5, 1), DATE(2019, 1, 5) - 1)
```

Rename auto-generated column "Date" into "Start Date". Add new column as

```
End Date = Start Date + 1
```